# Bootstrap css fails grunt-recess lint task (noOverqualifying)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, recess

Twitter's Bootstrap is failing its own recess linting. When running grunt-recess on [modals.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/modals.less#L32) I get overqualifying errors.

The offending code (in LESS):

```
.modal {

  ...

  // When fading in the modal, animate it to slide down
  &.fade .modal-dialog {
    .translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
    .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
  }
  &.in .modal-dialog { .translate3d(0, 0, 0) }
}
```

and

```
.modal-backdrop {

  ...

  // Fade for backdrop
  &.fade { .opacity(0); }
  &.in { .opacity(@modal-backdrop-opacity); }
}
```

After compiling the LESS with grunt-contrib-less, I run recess to lint the resulting app.css.

The grunt-recess output:

```
Running "recess:dist" (recess) task
Warning: FILE: public/css/app.css
STATUS: Busted
FAILURES: 4 failures

Element selectors should not be overqualified
       1. .modal.fade .modal-dialog

Element selectors should not be overqualified
       1. .modal.in .modal-dialog

Element selectors should not be overqualified
       1. .modal-backdrop.fade

Element selectors should not be overqualified
       1. .modal-backdrop.in
 Use --force to continue.
```

I don't know that these selectors *are* overqualified, without the `.modal` and `.modal-background` classes these selectors would be under specified and it breaks the modal css.

Comment: And what is your question? Bootstrap dropped `recess` support in v3.0.1 so strictly speaking it's no longer "its own" (and if I'm not mistaken the overqualifying option was off anyway for Bootstrap compilation even before that).

Comment: My question was just generally how to resolve this - either by editing the LESS in a non-breaking way, or by figuring out why recess is complaining about selectors that (in my mind) aren't overqualified. Didn't know Bootstrap had dropped recess support, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I guess the proper way to fix this would be just to turn the option off for Bootstrap based CSS (i.e. [noOverqualifying: true](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess#options) or so). I can't see a way to edit these files in a *non-breaking* way (especially considering that those `modal` classes may be also used by corresponding [scripts](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)).

Answer (score 1):

First, when using Bootstrap you should ignore these errors, or consider your own Bootstrap, as also mentioned in the comments these classes are also used in Bootstrap jQuery plugins.

Secondly you should wonder if fixing really will fix the underlying problem, see also https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-overqualified-elements:

> This rule is aimed at decreasing byte count by removing extra
>   unnecessary qualifiers from selectors.

Your tests seems to fail on doubles selectors such as `.classa.classb` meaning having both `classa` and `classb`. Theoretical you can define a new class for that situation, Which could save you some bytes if you choose a name shorter than `.classa.classb`.
But in Bootstrap the `.in` and `.fade` classes describe states (compare with `:hover` and `:active`) and are not unnecessary at all.